# Including line breaks & bullet points in a Facebook graph post function

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to allow my users to post a bulleted list from my webapp to their Facebook feed. The list is created in a form (with bullets & line breaks) that can then be edited and submitted.

My code works fine when sending regular text (posting the form contents to FB feed), but it breaks when the message has bullets (●`&#x25cf;`) and line breaks (`&#13;&#10;`) aren't recognized.

I've tried a bunch of different ways of encoding the message, but none of them work. Here's my FB function:

```
  <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '(MYID)',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.0'
    });
    FB.login(function(){
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {message: '<?=$share_text;?>'});
    }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
   </script>
```

My questions are how should I encode `$share_text`, which comes from a POST form, and should I use a different way to write bullets & line breaks so that Facebook understands there are bullets and line breaks?

If I copy bullets and line breaks into a status update they work fine, so I assume this is possible.

**EDIT:** I've narrowed the problem down to the line breaks. I can post bullets to FB if there are no line breaks in the text. I think the issue is that html encoding of `<BR />` includes `;`'s.

Thanks

Comment: The message the user them self need to manually type every single character. You are saying that they are adding linebreaks and bullets?

Comment: I add the line breaks and bullets initially, but the user has the ability to edit them before submitting the dialog to share on FB. I obviously want the line breaks and bullets to be processed correctly on the FB share side of things.

Comment: You are not allowed to prefill the message. The user have to type every single character in the message

Comment: I can prefill the message just fine as long as I don't put in bullets or line breaks. If I put bullets/line breaks in, it breaks. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.1#graphapi That link outlines exactly what I did, I just replaced "hello, world" with whatever I want to post.

Comment: You can not prefill the message according to Facebook Platform Policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy .

Comment: Well it let's me do it by simply following the steps in their tutorial. Either way, that's not the issue. The issue is when special characters are in the message.

Comment: I didn't say it was technically impossible. I said it wasn't allowed. When you apply for the publish_actions permission that you will need they will deny the request because you are not following the policy

Comment: I just watched the video regarding Section 2.3 - Prefilling Content. My method is completely within the guidelines. Users submit different lines of text to me. They click a button to share this text. I show them a text box that gets filled with the text they already gave me and tell them they can share to Facebook. If they click Share, it posts that exact message to Facebook. I don't append anything to their message and I don't auto-fill anything into their message. I show them the message they chose to share so they can edit it, then I post it if they say OK. It is not a policy violation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The problem was the line breaks themselves.

My solution was to take a textarea input `$input`, change all the line breaks to `<br />` via `nl2br($input)`,

replace all the `<br />` to `\r\n\r\n` via `str_replace('<br />','\r\n\r\n',nl2br($input))` because Facebook recognizes `\r\n\r\n` as a new line

and then remove all hidden line breaks via `preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "",str_replace('<br />','\r\n\r\n',nl2br($share)));`

Taking the user's form input and running it through that last `preg_replace` function allows Facebook to read it correctly and post a bulletted list with line breaks!