# Facebook graph api line breaks

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have an application which publishes on facebook page. Idea is to submit whole articles with multiple paragraphs on an FB page, but turns out that facebook is not allowing any line breaks. As a result, all paragraphs are merged together and make the post ugly. Is there any FB guideline to add line breaks? because I've researched a lot and was unable to find one.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the actual message part of a post, or the description of shared links?

Comment: @CBroe Actual message part. Links are not posted. Just a 200-500 words  article on a page.

Comment: Line breaks in the message part should be absolutely no problem. Make sure to use \n, or whatever your language’s equivalent of that is.

Comment: @CBroe \n appears as \n and <br> as <br>. Take a look [link]https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=1254806737871412&id=1181771525174934[/link].

Comment: That is actually description part I think. Sorry for early misunderstanding.

Comment: Well, in description you can not use line breaks. You can try to replace them with another character perhaps to at least get _some_ form of “separation” between what (in your system) would be different paragraphs – such as inserting a bullet point or similar in between.

Comment: There is a service called kuku.io, which sends the posts with line breaks on facebook. I don't know how they pulled that one out. Every developer whom I know, says that adding line breaks in facebook description part is impossible. I'm under a lot of pressure due to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed. At least some separation is there between paragraphs. I tried the solution from this post and it worked perfectly. [Including line breaks & bullet points in a Facebook graph post function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319926/including-line-breaks-bullet-points-in-a-facebook-graph-post-function)